# How does hbase find the latest version of data?

Tags: hbase

In my understanding, habase should traverse a part of hfile in order to find the data needed. I do the following experiement:

I create a table using the following command:

```
create 'test', {'NAME' => 'cf', VERSIONS => 1}
```

Then I insert a row:

```
put 'test', 'row1', 'cf:a', 'data1'
```

From the get command `get 'row1'`you can see the following output:

```
COLUMN                CELL
cf:a                 timestamp= 1520570145471, value=data1
```

After that I insert a lot of data in order to let hbase flush the data into hfile, totaly 100000 rows and flush with command as follows:

```
flush 'test'
```

And at last I update the row inserted first through the following command:

```
put 'test', 'row1', 'cf:a', 'data2', 1520570145371
```

What you must notice is that the update timestamp is smaller than the previous timestamp. Then I find that hbase can also find the large version of data, how can hbase do this? Is hbase scan through all the hfile to find all the versions of this row?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [docs](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/versions.html), A {row, column, version} tuple exactly specifies a cell in HBase. The HBase version dimension is stored in decreasing order, so that when reading from a store file, the most recent values are found first.

By default, when doing a get, the cell whose version has the largest value is returned (which may or may not be the latest one written).

Comment: @Saurahb But hdfs is append only file system, So if update a column to a new version it will be stored into another hfile, in other words the new version and the old version is not in the same hfile. Although the major compaction will compact them together, there still a period of time that they are in different hfile.